# CardView java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: radius must be > 0

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-cardview, cardview

in api 17 when I attempt to set card-view radius to zero, an exception occures that says "radius must be > 0". code:

```
mediaPlayerCardView.radius = 0F
```

Comment: Can you provide the code of both xml and Kotlin regarding of this `CardView`?

Comment: Use a `MaterialCardView` instead of the `CardView`

Answer (score 0):

Try to set it in xml:

```
app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
```

Comment: I want to set it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MaterialCardView` instead of the `CardView` and apply

```
mediaPlayerCardView.radius = 0F
```